# Delete number from the beginning

Tags: java, regex, string

I have some strings that begin with a number and a whitespace and I want to extract everything after that whitespace.

First string:

```
1 abc def
```

What I want:

```
abd def
```

Second string:

```
1 23 abs
```

What I want:

```
23 abs
```

What is the best way to do it in Java?
I know it can be achieved by regular expressions and String methods, but which way is the shortest?

Comment: Regex. Or String functions.

Comment: `String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`

Comment: You can try: `str = str.substring(str.indexOf(" "))` this will work if as you said there will be a whitespace after the first number

Comment: To do it efficiently you should avoid the regex methods like `split`, `replace` and `replaceAll` and simply find the index of the first space, then use substring from the position after that index to grab the rest of the string. Far more efficient than engaging the regex engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^[0-9]+ ", "");
```

Comment: what if the number size is greater than 1 digit?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo he used `+` to check for that

Comment: replace first works for first character or sequence?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo number size doesn't matter if you use replaceFirst, it will only replace first character from string.

Comment: @Apurva i forget to add ^ to my regex. replaceFirst, will replace the first sequence found by Regex, and not at the first position. i have corrected my response :)

Comment: @Titus was put later on when I asked him to modify :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
String str = "1 abc def";
String split[] = str.split(" ", 2);
System.out.println(split[1]);
```